# How do Hide/Mask id from url in react

Tags: reactjs

How do Hide/Mask id from url in react..
here is my code:

```
<Link to={`/renderform/${item._id}`} >
<td>{item.formName}</td>
</Link>

<Route path="/renderform/:formId" element={<FormRenderComp />} />
```

this code is working fine, now i want to hide the id

Answer (score 0):

Your design is based on the fact that the URL contains the id. It is a nice and standard way to handle a state for your app, and have URLs that describe what they do. If you really want to obfuscate ids, you need to deeply modify this design.

You could use another unique identifiers for your forms, like CMS do to generate URL for articles (based on article title in general). Eg `/render/1234` would become `/renderform/my-form-title-slugified` for example. But you would need to set up a mechanism to generate those unique slugs which is not trivial.

You could also try to store the clicked form id in another state management tool, like Redux, Recoil, MobX, or a parent component state. You would need to, when an item is clicked, store the item id in your state, then in the detail page (`/renderform`) you could read that id, fetch the item and display it.